# How to replace invalid datetime string with a correct format of datetime string when using DateTime.ParseExact()?

Tags: c#, string, linq, datetime

I would like to order my list based on a string type property that contains DateTime. In order to do that, I convert the string property into DateTime inside the `OrderBy()` or `OrderByDescending()`. So here is my code:

```
var orderDirection = "ASC";

//AList already contains data.
AList = (orderDirection.Equals("ASC", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) 
   ? AList
      .OrderBy(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x.LastUpdate, "g", WebCulture))
      .ToList() 
   : AList
      .OrderByDescending(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x.LastUpdate, "g", WebCulture))
      .ToList();
```

Unfortunately, it works fine only if `x.LastUpdate` contains valid format of DateTime. Otherwise it will throw error.

Therefore, is there any way to let's say alter that invalid datetime string with a valid datetime string in `ParseExact()`? Or is there any other function that can provide that?

For example, it would be like, "convert the string into datetime, but for the invalid string, replace it with "1-1-1990 00:00:00.000"?

Comment: You can use `TryParseExact` for example. Or even not store dates as strings but make your `LastUpdate` of type DateTime right away.

Comment: For using `TryParseExact`, can you show me how to state it inside `OrderBy()` ? Because basically, for `TryParseExact`, it has bool value, hasn't it?

Comment: @Evk For some reasons, the property type has to be string unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

what about a simple condition inside the `OrderBy()`

```
AList.OrderBy(x =>
{
    DateTime result;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(x.LastUpdate, out result))
        return result;
    return new DateTime(1990, 1, 1);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `DateTime.TryParseExact` instead `DateTime.ParseExact`:

```
  var records = AList
    .Select(x => {
       bool valid = DateTime.TryParseExact(x.LastUpdate, "g", WebCulture, out date);

       return {
         valid = valid,
         date = date,
         value = x;
       }});

   AList = (orderDirection.Equals("ASC", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) 
     ? records
         .OrderBy(x => x.valid)
         .ThenBy(x => x.date)
         .Select(x => x.value)
         .ToList()
     : records
         .OrderByDescending(x => x.valid)
         .ThenByDescending(x => x.date)
         .Select(x => x.value)
         .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could provide an extension method that returns a `DateTime?` if the format is not valid:

```
public static DateTime? TryGetDateTime(this string str, IFormatProvider provider, string format = null)
{
    DateTime dt;
    bool valid = format == null 
        ? DateTime.TryParse(str, provider, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt) 
        : DateTime.TryParseExact(str, format, provider, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);

    if (valid)
        return dt;
    else
        return null;
}
```

Then the query is straight forward:

```
AList = AList
    .Select(s => new { s, dt = s.TryGetDateTime(WebCulture) })
    .OrderBy(x => x.dt.GetValueOrDefault())
    .Select(x => x.s)
    .ToList();
```

(for the asc/desc logic just use `if...else` and replace `Orderby` with `OrderByDescending`)